# TweetInvi authenticating but not performing search

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

I seem to be having issues carrying out basic searches using this library, i can authenticate fine:

**Code:**

```
//var userCredentials = Auth.CreateCredentials(twitter.TwitterAPIKey, twitter.TwitterAPISecretKey, twitter.TwitterAPIAccessToken, twitter.TwitterAPIAccessTokenSecret);
//var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser(userCredentials);
//Auth.SetCredentials(twitter.TwitterAPIKey, twitter.TwitterAPISecretKey, twitter.TwitterAPIAccessToken, twitter.TwitterAPIAccessTokenSecret);

var cred = Auth.SetUserCredentials(twitter.TwitterAPIKey, twitter.TwitterAPISecretKey, twitter.TwitterAPIAccessToken, twitter.TwitterAPIAccessTokenSecret);
var user = User.GetAuthenticatedUser(cred);

Helpers.ReturnMessage(user.ScreenName);

var searchParameter = new SearchTweetsParameters("dogs")
{
    GeoCode = new GeoCode(-122.398720, 37.781157, 1, DistanceMeasure.Miles),
    Lang = LanguageFilter.English,
    SearchType = SearchResultType.Popular,
    MaximumNumberOfResults = 100,
    Until = new DateTime(2015, 06, 02),
    SinceId = 399616835892781056,
    MaxId = 405001488843284480,
    Filters = TweetSearchFilters.Images | TweetSearchFilters.Verified
};

var tweets = Search.SearchTweets(searchParameter);
var tweetCount = tweets.Count();

Helpers.ReturnMessage(tweetCount.ToString());

foreach (var tweet in tweets) {
    Helpers.ReturnMessage(tweet.FullText);
}
```

This part `Helpers.ReturnMessage(user.ScreenName);` will display the screenname fine, which is correct when viewed, drilling down the error being thrown is: `Tweetinvi.Exceptions.TwitterNullCredentialsException: Exception of type 'Tweetinvi.Exceptions.TwitterNullCredentialsException' was thrown`

But the credentials are fine when testing, i wouldn't have got the screenname if they were wrong, has anyone used this library, am i doing somehting obviously wrong, any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am the main developer of Tweetinvi.

From my understanding you are receiving this issue when calling the line `var tweets = Search.SearchTweets(searchParameter);`

If this is the case then it is definitely a bug. it could be worth opening a bug on Github.

In the meantime, I would suggest you use Tweetinvi 5.0 which has been rebuilt and includes different bug fixes.

Here is the documentation [link for the search in 5.0](https://linvi.github.io/tweetinvi/dist/twitter-api/search.html).

Let me know if this helps.

Cheers,
Linvi